# How to get the value of a select_tag item while still on a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Here's my select_tag item:

```
<%= select_tag :room_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Room.all, "id", "to_s") %>
```

**Question**: How can I get the selected value of a select_tag object on my form - **while still on the form**? *(not using params[:room_id] inside the controller after it has been submitted)*

In other words, I know I can use params[:room_id] in the controller once I've submitted the form. All of my searches about this question seem to tell me to just use params[:room_id]. What I need to do is simply to get the value of the select_tag item while still on the form and use it.

for example: `<%= local_var = (value of select_tag) %>`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a client side scripting language such as JavaScript or the jQuery library as shown below:

`$( "#id_of_select_element" ).val();`